# how do I make python selenium file into an exe file with pyinstaller

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pyinstaller, exe

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

for i in range(1, 6):
    try:
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options)
        browser.maximize_window()
        browser.get("http://instagram.com")
        time.sleep(2)
        elem = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "_aa4b")[0]
        elem.send_keys("test")
        elem2 = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "_aa4b")[1]
        elem2.send_keys("test")
        elem3 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]')
        elem3.click()
        time.sleep(3)
      
        elem4 = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "x5n08af")[0]
        elem4.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        elem5 = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "_a9--")[1]
        elem5.click()
        time.sleep(2)

        while True:
            try:
                elems = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "xyb1xck")
                for e in elems:
                    e.click()
                    time.sleep(1)
                browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
                time.sleep(2)
            except:
                break

        time.sleep(3)
        browser.quit()
    except:
        continue
```

I made this file into an exe file, but instead of chrome window, cmd appears and disappears soon.

Is making python file using selenium into an exe file different with other python files?

Comment: have you tried running the exe from the cli to see whether you get any errors?

Comment: No i didn't. How do I run exe from the cli?

Comment: Open a command prompt window, navigate to the folder the exe is in, and then run it.

Comment: in addition to what Gabriel said, "run it" is something like: type `myapp.exe` (adjust to the actual name) and then hit Return.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are executing the command in the virtual environment.

With cmd in Scripts folder of your venv execute `activate.bat`.

After that run pyintaller command.

Run your .exe with cmd to view errors.